# R code - Use of periodReturn function (quantmod package)

Tags: r, quantmod

Dear Stack overflow community, I am trying to compute the returns of an asset using periodReturn's quantmod functions:

HLCtest is a "High Low Close" object, head(HLCtest) gives:

```
##       Date          High     low     Close
##1  1991-01-01 GMT  1517.93  1517.93  1517.93   
##2  1991-01-02 GMT  1509.58  1487.96  1505.10
##3  1991-01-03 GMT  1540.22  1500.54  1539.50
##4  1991-01-04 GMT  1552.15  1533.77  1547.66
##5  1991-01-07 GMT  1524.38  1501.26  1507.87
##6  1991-01-08 GMT  1507.37  1474.79  1500.24

> yearlyReturn(HLCtest, subset=NULL, type='arithmetic', leading=TRUE)
```

I get the following error message:

```
> Error in try.xts(x) : 
  Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) :   character string is not in a    standard unambiguous format
```

I used:

```
> strftime(HLCtest$Date, format ="", tz="GMT", usetz = TRUE)
```

to make sure the date format was ISO8601 standard.

and also: 
`> is.HLC(HLCtest)` to make sure the object was "High Low Close" object.

Could someone please tell me what is this error message telling me and how to fix it?

Comment: show some sample data, i.e.`head(HLCtest)`

Comment: Please se the modifications beneath. Tks rbm.

Comment: OK, that's not enough - can you show a reproducible example, incl. getting the data? Im guessing you're either downloading the data via `getSymbols` or you need to `dput` the data (at least first few rows.

Comment: That won't help. Update question with `dput` output of first 5 rows of `HLCtest`

Comment: Please see the modification beneath. I get the data trough a .csv file and I'am afraid I can't use dput() for it returns a huge amount of data in the Console and I can't even see the command typed and the beginning of the results..

Comment: You can't paste the output of `dput(HLCtest[1:5,])` ?

Comment: That I can (sorry i'm new R user^^)! if I data.frame(dput(HLCtest2[1:5, ])), I get the same result than the one in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yearlyReturn` doesn't know how to convert your data.frame to an xts object.  This is because it uses `try.xts` to attempt to convert it to an xts object, and `try.xts` expects the data.frame row names to contain the dates.

The easiest solution is to create an xts object yourself, and then pass that to `yearlyReturn`.

```
# sample data
y <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(7670, 7671, 7672, 7673, 7676, 
7677), class = "Date"), High = c(1517.93, 1509.58, 1540.22, 1552.15, 
1524.38, 1507.37), low = c(1517.93, 1487.96, 1500.54, 1533.77, 
1501.26, 1474.79), Close = c(1517.93, 1505.1, 1539.5, 1547.66, 
1507.87, 1500.24)), .Names = c("Date", "High", "low", "Close"),
row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
# make xts object
x <- xts(y[,-1], y[,1])
# call *lyReturn
dailyReturn(x)
#            daily.returns
# 1991-01-01   0.000000000
# 1991-01-02  -0.005500912
# 1991-01-03   0.020297036
# 1991-01-04   0.007745647
# 1991-01-07  -0.017891312
# 1991-01-08  -0.011158635
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works like a charm! You are right, the periodReturn functions expect the data.frame row name to contain the dates..

Comment: Glad it's helpful, and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).